# NativeScript debug with WebStorm - breakpoints not being hit?

Tags: angular, webstorm, nativescript

I'm using WebStorm 2017.2.5 + NativeScript  3.3.1. ([package.json](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8f583cad9844c00e28e517903e2fdf5a))

I've created a run/debug configuration :

[image]

And also set breakpoints in :

[image]

And now I hit :

[image]

The app is running  - [`And here is the output from console`](http://jsbin.com/sicayileco/edit?html,output).

**Question**

WebStorm is not stopping in the breakpoints that I've attached. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you perhaps setting your breakpoints too early during code execution (entry file?) If that's the case, then you should place `debugger` statements at the key points where need to break, and initiate the debugging session with the `--debug-brk` flag, as explained in the following article: https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/chrome-devtools#debugger

**Why doesn't the debugger pause on entry files by default?** The debug inspector works on the main thread, where most of your javascript, and the one that you'll be debugging, executes. The --debug-brk is necessary to instruct the runtime(platform) to not run any code before the debugger has attached, so as to not execute a script before having a chance to work with the debugger.

It is possible that the script is parsed and executed first, before notifications of 'preset' breakpoints are sent to the inspector, however debugger statements are part of your code execution, so if your inspector is connected, it will most certainly pause.

Comment: I don't understand  - whould I or should I not open the chrome browser  ? can't I just see the breakpoint hit in webstorm ? I don't want them to be hit in browser.

Comment: I've managed to run it with that switch but I don't see the ts files : https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPc7v.png

Comment: My response is general in regards to debugging NativeScript apps. If you find a way, you can probably supply the same flag to the debug process that WebStorm starts, I just don't use it. And there are TS files, they just need to be executed first, and this is where you need to place `debugger` statements. The reason you break inside `ts_helpers` is because it's the first file ever to execute in your application. Just `Play (F8) - Continue execution`, and you will see your other files executed.

Comment: Thank you. it seems that only when [I add debuggger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHbLS.png) - I does hit the breakpoints (with ts files view). I was hoping that I could set the breakpoint in webstorm ( -_without_ debugger statement) - and to hit that line. Is it possible ?

Comment: Not if the script executes too early, the inspector would not have received the breakpoints information, at which point the application won't break. However the `debugger` statement guarantees that the application will pause and wait for actions sent from the debugger.

Comment: Thank you for your patience and answers.

Comment: I do see the breakpoint  but I don't see the TS version. https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoFsu.png - sourcemaps are included (according to the file : http://jsbin.com/vibuxifada/edit?html,output)

Comment: Could you try by changing the tsconfig setting to inline the sourceMaps?